# Unity build Issue: Difference in quality, maybye lights? IDK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when I play the game I'm coding in Unity I don't have any issues regarding on how the earth looks like. But once I build, It gets like this:

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction to fix this problem?

Thank you!